# On the effect of \mathstrut

Tags: tikz-pgf, strut

On page 1004/1318 of Tikz manual there is an example using \mathstrut.
I added more lines to the code to investigate what \mathstrut really does. I found that it makes the characters more aligned along the line (left hand side picture), otherwise the characters go up and down along the line (right hand side picture). Is my observation correct?

[image]

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,e}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,e}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=blue!50, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi,-\yi) {$\mathstrut\x\y$};
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,e}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,e}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=blue!50, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi+5,-\yi) {$\x\y$};
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-1.14) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-1.77) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-2.14) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-2.77) -- ++(9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathstrut` inserts an invisible box of the same height and depth as `(` and zero width, so the whole line will have at least the same height and depth as `(`.

Comment: Where the invisible box is drawn?

Comment: It is not drawn (which is the meaning of invisible).

Comment: I understand the width and height, but how the depth is defined in a 2 dimensional plane?

Comment: Can not understand the effect of the invisible box.

Comment: The extent of the line above the baseline is called height, its extent below it is called depth.  A line containing only `h` as zero depth, but a line with `g` has non-zero depth because the hook of the letter extends below the baseline.

Comment: @Aria - In TeX and LaTeX parlance, a typographic strut is a "box" with some height above the baseline and/or some depth below the baseline, *but no width*. It's therefore not visible; however, it may still have an effect on the placement of the line in which it's located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro `\mathstrut` inserts an invisible box with the height and depth of `(` and zero width.  You can visualize this effect using a nice package called `lua-visual-debug`.  It requires you to compile the document with LuaTeX though.  I have added

```
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
```

to the preamble and changed

```
$\mathstrut\x\y$ -> $\x\mathstrut\y$
```

to put the strut in the middle between the two letters.  Generally you should put always put the strut in the beginning because it can disrupt your spacing otherwise.  The result is

[image]

The faint grey boxes around the lines give an indication of the height and depth of the line and the grey vertical bar in the middle is the strut.

Comment: Thanks Henri. The baseline is tangent to the bottom round of "a", right?

Comment: @Aria Yes, that is correct.  If you have a node named `A` you can actually refer to its baseline using `(A.base)`.

Answer (score 2):

As we see the right hand side figure has some characters up and down with respect to the base line of the left hand side figure in which we used the \mathstrut. To see how we can align the characters on the right hand side the same as what we have in left hand side we can add a parenthesis at the beginning of each text in each block to appreciate the effect of the \mathstut as an invisible parenthesis:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,e}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,e}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=blue!50, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi,-\yi) {$\mathstrut\x\y$};
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,e}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,e}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=blue!50, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi+5,-\yi) {$(\x\y$};
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-1.14) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-1.77) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-2.14) -- ++(9,0);
\draw [red][|-|] (1,-2.77) -- ++(9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```